# JMeter 4.0 | AWS S3 Bucket | Non HTTP response message

Tags: amazon-s3, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-4.0

I have uploaded one video and image file in the S3 bucket.

- Video File:374 KB
- Image File:826 KB

Now, i have created the script add two HTTP Request for the two files which are located on the S3 bucket.

I executed the script on the distributed environment configured as below:

- Master Machine (My Machine)
- 2 Slaves Machine
- Thread: jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group
- Number of Threads: 100
  [image: User load configaration]

Once the script has been executed below errors are appearing:

- Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException/Non HTTP response message: Connection reset
- Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException/Non HTTP response message: Remote host closed connection during handshake
- Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException/Non HTTP response message: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed

**I am unable to identify what is causing these errors to arise:**

- Is it master machine or the slave machine?
- Or, there is some problem with S3 bucket, it is unable to handle the     requests?

**I have tried changing the HTTP Default request implementation to HTTPClient4 changed the user.properties as follows:**

- httpclient4.retrycount=1 and
- hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters

And hc.parameters file:

- http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true

**Can anyone help me to identify the problem? and how can i solve these errors?**

Server Configuration:

- Application Server: 2
- Database: RDS
- Elastic Load Balancing
- S3 bucket

Comment: first try to download the file without your script and start discarding problems...

Comment: @Carlos  The files are accessible through the browser. Can you shed some light on your comment.